# appcfg.py is not running with cmd prompt (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, cmd, scripting-language

I am having strange problem. I used to run appcfg.py to update my app to appengine but now its not working anymore. When I run this command

```
C:\Program Files <x86>\Google\google_appengine>appcfg.py update E:\path\myApp\
```

Its not giving me anything, no error no feedback. Its just back to this line

```
C:\Program Files <x86>\Google\google_appengine>
```

Any idea about this issue!

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7. My code is updating through google app launcher but I need to run it from cmd prompt as I will be downloading/uploading appengine stuff which launcher doesn't allow me to do!

Thanks

Comment: `python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"`

Answer (score 2):

I still had a little trouble with the instructions. Here's the steps I used to create a batch file to use the Google App Engine download_app with Windows 7.

In my example,

- I'll use drive, **C:**
- Default python path will be, **C:\Python27\python.exe**
- GAE path (include "), **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"**
- App ID **{your_app_id}** will be just your app-id name
- **{your_app_version}** is the "Version:" number in your GAE app.yaml file
- I'll create a folder on my Windows 7 desktop and call it **GAE_App**
- The desktop folder path will be **C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\GAE_App**
- **{your email}** will be the Gmail account connected to your GAE

Right-click on the desktop and select New->Text Document. Open the newly created text document and add the following line of code modified for your setup to the blank text document,

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" download_app -A {your_app_id} -V {your_app_version} --email={your email} C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\GAE_App
```

Save the text document and change the file name to **GAE_Download.bat**

It's important that the extension now says ".bat" instead of ".txt"

Once finished, click on the batch to execute it. You'll be asked for a password and then the files should download into the **GAE_App** folder on your desktop. Now, whenever you need to download your files, just click on the batch file.

Not sure why Google didn't simply include this feature with their GAE for Windows software.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Here is a simple solution. 
Just do this following Steps:

1. Go to program file where google app engine is installed. Generally It is named as Google.
2. click on appcfg.py and select open with.. Select "Choose Default Programs".
3. Select Python from programs and select "Always Use the selected program to open this kind of file" .
4. Now run the command you should get the results on command line.

[For reference click here](https://wordpress.com/post/44779096/125)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by accessing python lib like that

C:\Python27>python appcfg.py update E:\path\myApp\

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me:
 "google_appengine/appcfg.py" update "C:\PATH TO APP

Answer (score 0):

The appcfg.bat that should be used is located **C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\appengine-java-sdk\bin** and *not* the empty appcfg.bat that for some unknown reason also was here C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\

Good practice is to add this path to the system variable PATH

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

**Basis**

```
<PATH_TO_PYTHON>python <PATH_TO_APPCFG.PY>appcfg.py -A <PROJECT_INSTANCE_NAME> update app.yaml
```

**Example**

```
X:\Software\Python2.7\python Q:\SOFTWARE\GoogleAppEngineSDK\appcfg.py -A great-1337 update app.yaml
```